# Windows desktop background: how to have system info displayed

Tags: windows, desktop-customization, resource-usage

Some Windows machines can be configured with a desktop background that will query the local system for its hardware configuration, OS, configuration, statistics, etc.

[image]

What program do you need to install to acquire this type of desktop background?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That appears to be SysInternals' [BGInfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557.aspx).

It's a [stand-alone executable](http://download.sysinternals.com/files/BGInfo.zip) that you place in your `StartUp` directory. You can create a Windows scheduled task to refresh it at an interval you choose.

BGInfo basically writes a new desktop bitmap image every time it is executed.

You can pick and choose the data presented, its fonts, colors, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[Rainmeter](http://code.google.com/p/rainmeter/) is popular once you've [skinned](http://customize.org/rainmeter) it to show [system data](http://browse.deviantart.com/customization/skins/sysmonitor/rainmeter/#order=9).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the info about rainmeter!  very cool!

Answer (score 0):

Update to location.  The original location at code.google is no longer used.

https://www.rainmeter.net/

or

https://github.com/rainmeter/rainmeter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1106271)